# keras predicts nan values

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I implemented a Keras model for my all-integer dataset with values greater than or equal to 0. The train data has dimensions of `(393, 108)` and prediction data has `(1821, 108)`. Code is as follows.

```py
import keras    
from keras.models import Sequential    
from keras.layers import Dense

X = data.iloc[:, :-1]
y = data.iloc[:, -1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(X.shape[1]-1, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='tanh'))

for i in range(X.shape[1] - 2, 2, -100):
    model.add(Dense(i, activation='tanh'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=100)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
model.fit(X, y)
model.predict(X0)
```

I am getting all `nan` values as results.

```
array([[nan],
       [nan],
       [nan],
       ...,
       [nan],
       [nan],
       [nan]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your input is not standardized
- The learning rate is way too high, start with the Default *i.e. 0.001*

**Other suggested changes -**

- Use "relu" in the hidden/input layer
- OHE the target
- If the target is multi-class, the output layer should have same number of Neurons with softmax as activation
- Data points are very less, Neural Net might not be the best option

Comment: I standardized the input, changed learning rate to 0.001, used "tanh" for hidden/input layer, "softmax" for the output. The output layer has 8 neurons where I expect 3 different classes. When I make the output function "sigmoid" I get values between 0,7 and 0,3 where my output values should be 2,3 or 4.

Comment: For 3 Classes, have 3 Neurons and Softmax.OHE the target. Rest is part of tuning the Network

Comment: Now I have 3 neurons and softmax. I OHEd the target. I got the results and reverse OHEd them with np.argmax to see categorical values. Now I need to tune the nn to get a better accuracy. Thank you very much.